# Random domain when using telnet on my server's IP

Tags: domain-name-system, security, web-hosting, telnet

I was preparing a new website on my cloud server and before changing the domain's pointing IP I decided to use telnet to make a quick test.

Since each site is a vhost I can use a different domain (which points to the same server) and I get a result like this:

```
$ telnet domain.example.com 80
Trying <server.ip>...
Connected to domain.example.com.
...
```

All good, but then I tried to connect to the IP directly:

```
$ telnet <server.ip> 80
```

And got an interesting response:

```
Trying <server.ip>...
Connected to <different-domain.com>.
```

Where is this unknown different-domain coming from? Is it a random thing? Does it mean I've got a security problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that in the DNS this IP address has a PTR record pointing to `different-domain.com`. Do a `dig -x <server.ip>` and you will see the name. For HTTP traffic, that will not create any kind of problems (the situation would be different for emails). You do not have a security problem just from that configuration case.